# Beamer-Button which opens a browser with an URL

Tags: beamer, urls

is it possible to use a beamerbutton for presentations which would open a browser and a given URL?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use [any linking command from hyperref](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.pdf) to make links from beamer buttons. For example the following uses `\href` to link a button to this question:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20800/5701}{\beamergotobutton{Link}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be nice to know how to style the contents of the `\href`, i.e. if you're not using a button, how to make the text blue and underlined.

Comment: I was always looking for this but did not know how to do it. Thanks for great help!

Comment: How can we change color of the url button?