# Can I create a shortcut to another program with LaTeX Beamer class?

Tags: beamer, hyperref, external-files

I am just about to create my `beamer` file for my upcoming presentation in which I need to open another program (NetLogo if it helps) to show it to the audience. Is there any possibility to create a shortcut or link so that I only have to press 'next' or click on that shortcut to open the program?
Or do I have to close the PDF my self and open the other program?

I'd be most thankful for your answers.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and see if this helps you [Beamer-Button which opens a browser with an URL](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20803/15717)

Comment: Welcome @Clarina. There is no need to add a _Thanks_ to your questions, just upvote answers is sufficient. There is always your _namebadge_ below your question, so there is no need to sign your question, too.

Comment: @texenthusiast No sorry, I don't want to open a website.

Comment: @Clarina i am unaware of what is `NetLogo` ? if you can add details on it how you open normally without beamer,it will help. see [A button that runs an external program from a Beamer PDF presentation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22960/15717)

Comment: @Clarina my suggestion is: Don't run any executables from `.pdf` it's not good for security reasons, incase you share the file. Too much automation is also not good. May be minimise the .pdf and open the `Netlogo` while you mesmerise the audience with your witty talk.