# Hyperlink at Beamer for external files

Tags: beamer, hyperref, hyperlink, href, hypertarget

I need to do hypperlink to external file to hyppertarget in it . is it possible to do this ?
I read about href and url ,but I didn`t find info about this . Tex file with hyppertarget will be placed in one directory with tex file with hyperref . Please ,help.

Like this  [Does hyperref work between two files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/does-hyperref-work-between-two-files)  ,but in beamer

Comment: Read the `hyperref` package documentation. It would be kind to provide a MWE, you will certainly get a quicker answer… You have some example of hyperref within beamer here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20800/beamer-button-which-opens-a-browser-with-an-url/20803#20803

Comment: Hyper linking in basic terms is going from one location to another label (named destination) That label can be a web <#address> a ToC or other tagged entry in a PDF, a bookmark in XL.spreadsheet/word.docx When beamer is compiled to pdf it is just like any other PDF subject to system restrictions etc. So short answer yes a pdf hyper link will try to go to wherever you steer it Simplest of all is to say mailto:me@home (or any email address) & with luck the system allows email app to open with the recipient filled in. Make URL call to go to core of other.pdf, more difficult so many ways per link.