# Why do some links break “href{…}{…}” in Beamer documentclass?

Tags: beamer, hyperref, href

Consider the following MWE (borrowed from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20800/beamer-button-which-opens-a-browser-with-an-url)):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20800/5701}{Link}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Such a MWE compiles without errors, yielding the expected output. Consider now this MWE, in which I have only changed the link for a Google Scholar link:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\href{https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=equilibrium+points+in+n-person+games&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5#}{Link}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Now, the MWE compiles with a few errors. Why does changing the link break `href`? How to stop this from happening?

**EDIT!** I see two options proposed in the answers: one is to escape the character `#` and the other one is to add `[fragile]` to my frame. Can any TeX expert tip the balance in favour of either option? What is the most Tex-y to do?

Comment: use \begin{frame}[fragile]

Comment: my argument is that this happens very often with many links due to anchor using `#` in the url. So, to me, this question isn't strictly `beamer` dependant.

Comment: @anis It is strictly beamer dependent due to the way beamer parses the frame environment.  It will work without error in normal classes in which the link isn't enclosed in an environment which is parsed multiple times, e.g. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=equilibrium+points+in+n-person+games&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5#}{Link}
\end{document}
`

Comment: @Hector What's not clear to me is why you need the # at the end at all? The link seems to give the same result with or without it.

Comment: @anis: hyperref handles links with `#` fine as long as you don't use such links in the argument of another command (as is done here in \frame).

Comment: @Hector: escaping is faster, but handles only the `#`. Using fragile will also allow you to use `%` in the link, and to use verbatim and listings in the frame.

Comment: I just realised that I do not need the `#` at the end of my link as it works just fine without it; but I did not know this when I copied-pasted the Google Scholar link from the address bar.

Comment: In a nutshell, escaping is faster and more general. right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `#` at the end of your link. You can work around it by using a fragile frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\href{https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=equilibrium+points+in+n-person+games&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5#}{Link}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `#` in the second link. Escaping that character solves it : `\#`